# Bootstrap-Multiselect Dropdown doesn't open after Ajax call

Tags: ajax, dropdown, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a modal popup, which shows by Ajax form. It includes the Bootstrap-Multiselect form. The problem is the Dropdown doesn't open the select list. I tried many options, include destroy, refresh, but it sill doesn't work.

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-modal', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var parts = this.id.split("-"); //Split block
        var string =  parts[parts.length - 1]; //receive last 
        var myData = 'modal_show='+ string; //receive data for POST

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "../ajax/modal.php", 
            dataType:"text", 
            data:myData, 
            success:function(response){
                $("#all-modal").html(response);  
                $('#physical-modal, #modal-overlay').css({'display':'block'});  
                $('.smart-multiselect').multiselect('destroy');
                $('.smart-multiselect').multiselect({nonSelectedText: 'Select optional'});
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        })
 })
```

Comment: Solved, by adding $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

Comment: can you show the answer i got the same issue

Comment: @TimSadvak What is  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(); can yo provide the example

Comment: @TimSadvak this worked for me also $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();